# Oracle Apex,is it possible to connect an excel file or csv from a remote server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, remote-server

I am creating a web app using **Oracle apex** and I need to draw data from an excel file or CSV file from a **remote server**, is the remote server option of oracle apex capable of that, is it possible to be done and how? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the "**Data Loading**" page type, then yes - the Wizard creates several pages; one of them lets you browse for the source file. If the remote server's directory is **mapped** on your computer, you'll see it while browsing for the file and use it as data source.

Comment: Actually, I am not talking about the data loading page type , I am talking about data loading from a server in general, for example, I choose an app then from shared components I try to create a remote server,  can i point it to an excel file or CSV so that I can use its data for a report page type ? Thanks for the reply